scrollTo is not a function in Vue.js
I have a Vue component to show the posts from a database which include images and videos:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import { axiosConfig } from '@/config/axios';

const posts = ref<any[]>([]);

const fetchPosts = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('/posts', axiosConfig);
        posts.value = response.data.posts.sort((a: any, b: any) => new Date(b.createdAt).getTime() - new Date(a.createdAt).getTime());
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch posts:', error);
    }
};

const isImage = (fileUrl: string): boolean => {
    const imageExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg'];
    const fileExtension = fileUrl.split('.').pop()?.toLowerCase();
    return imageExtensions.includes(fileExtension || '');
};

const isVideo = (fileUrl: string): boolean => {
    const videoExtensions = ['mp4', 'webm', 'ogg', 'avi', 'mov', 'flv'];
    const fileExtension = fileUrl.split('.').pop()?.toLowerCase();
    return videoExtensions.includes(fileExtension || '');
};

const mediaItems = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

const scrollMedia = (direction: number) => {
    if (mediaItems.value) {
        const scrollAmount = mediaItems.value.scrollLeft + direction * 220;
        mediaItems.value.scrollTo({
            left: scrollAmount,
            behavior: 'smooth',
        });
    }
};

onMounted(() => {
    fetchPosts();
});
</script>

<template>
    <div class="post-container">
        <div class="post" v-for="post in posts" :key="post._id">
            <div class="media-post">
                <button class="post-nav-btn" @click="scrollMedia(-1)">&#10094;</button>
                <div class="media-post-items" ref="mediaItems">
                    <div v-for="(file, index) in post.uploaded" :key="index" class="media-post-item-wrapper">
                        <div class="media-post-item">
                            <img v-if="isImage(file.media)" :src="file.media" alt="Post media" />
                            <video v-else-if="isVideo(file.media)" :src="file.media" controls></video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="post-nav-btn" @click="scrollMedia(1)">&#10095;</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.post-container {
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
.post {
    width: 600px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.media-post {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.media-post img, .media-post video {
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    object-fit: contain;
}
.media-post-item {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    min-height: 220px;
}
/* some post-nav-btn CSS */
.media-post-items {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    gap: 10px;
}
</style>

The media files are shown but I cannot use post-nav-btn to horizontally scroll. When I click on the post-nav-btn, in browser console, it says:
Uncaught TypeError: mediaItems.value.scrollTo is not a function
<br>at Proxy.scrollMedia (Post.vue:34:26)
<br>at _createElementVNode.onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (Post.vue:59:54)
<br>at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:195:19)
<br>at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:202:17)
<br>at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:696:5)


mediaItems.value is an array because you used v-for. It's unclear how is it supposed to work, considering there are multiple elements to scroll

post.uploaded contains multiple media files. I display all of them in a row and I limit the screen width and I am able to scroll them horizontally by dragging the horizontal scroll bar. Now I add 2 post-nav-btn on the left and right side of the screen so when I click on the btn, it will scroll and I don't have to drag the scroll bar.

I meant posts loop, not post.uploaded. There are multiple posts and each has media-post-items, they are collected in mediaItems ref array
